# Partial classes in Google Closure?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure

Is it possible, using Google Closure compiler, to define a class in two files? For example, if I auto-generate one class and want to keep another one for user-entered code:

In MyClass.AutoGenerated.js

```
goog.provide("MyClass");
MyClass = function() {
}
MyClass.prototype.SomeMember = 15;
```

And then in MyClass.js, continue declaring members and functions:

```
MyClass.prototype.AnotherMember = 15;
MyClass.prototype.SomeAwesomeFunction = function() {};
```

Comment: See: **[Is there any reason not to provide the same module in different source files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12124813/1164465)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to come close to this, without relying on build order is this:

In MyClass.js

```
goog.provide("MyClass");
MyClass = function() {
}
MyClass.prototype.SomeMember = 15;
```

And then in MyClass.Partial.js, continue declaring members and functions **and provide a namespace with .Partial** (for example):

```
goog.require("MyClass");
goog.provide("MyClass.Partial");

MyClass.prototype.AnotherMember = 15;
MyClass.prototype.SomeAwesomeFunction = function() {};
```

Then the calling code must call:

```
goog.require("MyClass");
goog.require("MyClass.Partial");
```

in order to include both files in the right order. The *MyClass.Partial* class does not need to exist in any way; it is just an identifier used by the goog.require and goog.provide methods.

Answer (score 4):

As long as the files are ordered correctly this isn't a problem.  The ordering can be tricky however if it is possible to instantiate the class before the prototypes are filled out.